# Device mapper table alignment inconsistency

Tags: linux, device-mapper

In the journal, I'm getting lines such as:

```
Jan 27 18:23:08 tara kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:2: adding target device sdb2 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=33553920
Jan 27 18:23:08 tara kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:2: adding target device sdb2 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=33553920
Jan 27 18:23:08 tara kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:3: adding target device sdb2 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=34393292288
Jan 27 18:23:08 tara kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:3: adding target device sdb2 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=34393292288
```

How do I interpret this:

- What exactly is aligned incorrectly here?
- Where do the `start=` numbers come from?

How can I make the alignment consistent?

---

Further info:

```
[ravi@tara ~]$ uname -a
Linux tara 4.8.17-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 9 10:24:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[ravi@tara ~]$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk
sdb                   8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1                8:17   0  200M  0 part
└─sdb2                8:18   0  3.7T  0 part
  ├─usb-eMMC_backup 254:2    0   32G  0 lvm
  └─usb-ark         254:3    0  3.6T  0 lvm  /ark
sdc                   8:32   1  7.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1                8:33   1  7.5G  0 part
mmcblk0             179:0    0 29.1G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1         179:1    0  200M  0 part /mnt/esp
└─mmcblk0p2         179:2    0 28.9G  0 part
  ├─lvm-root        254:0    0   24G  0 lvm  /
  └─lvm-swap        254:1    0  4.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
mmcblk0boot0        179:8    0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1        179:16   0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk0rpmb         179:24   0    4M  0 disk
[ravi@tara ~]$
```

Comment: Note that apparently dmsetup can be mislead by this and actually create an alignment problem; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421587/dmsetup-luksformat-creating-an-alignment-inconsistency *(leaving this here for future readers)*

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection ... my question applies to your case too... Your LUKS data is misaligned. Unfortunately I doubt there is an easy fix if you've already got data on it (but maybe its not causing a performance issue for you, so you can just ignore)

Comment: @derobert I'm not using LUKS on this machine. The cause looks to be an [incorrectly reported optimal_io_size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496447/143394), but you may have the same root cause (USB attached SATA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Interpretation

The value first `start=` value of `33553920` is the offset of the first PE of the first LV in the target device (above `/dev/sdb2`).

This can be confirmed by:

```
sudo pvs -o +pe_start --units b
```

There is also another `start=` value repeated because `sdb2`'s VG contains two LVs (`usb-eMMC_backup` and `usb-ark`). I don't know why each is repeated though.

#### Cause

An alignment inconsistency exists because `pe_start` is not divisible by the `PHY-SEC` value of:

```
lsblk -t /dev/sdb
```

`PHY-SEC` was 4096, and 33553920 % 4096 != 0.

All LVs in the VG will be misaligned if `pe_start` is misaligned (with the default PE size of 4MiB).

#### Resolution

The VG will need to be created such that `pe_start` is divisible by the disk's sector size.

Passing `--dataalignment 1m` to `vgcreate` will have `pe_start` = 1048576B = 1MiB

#### What if I'm still getting `alignment inconsistency`?

Assuming the underlying partition is aligned, there may still be an (incorrect) alignment message generated.  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496606/143394) for a possible cause and resolution, especially if using USB attached SATA (UAS).

Answer (score 3):

The warning indicates that the partition and the LVM device may be misaligned, as defined by the checks in [blk_stack_limits](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/block/blk-settings.c?h=v4.12#n531).  You can examine the values from the output of `lsblk -t /dev/sdb` and check for the sorts of misalignments caught in `blk_stack_limits` (e.g. physical is multiple of logical block size, opt and min I/O are multiples of physical block size, etc.)

**Update 2019-03-03:** As @derobert pointed out in the comments, in this case the warnings are correct.  Your PV starts at byte 33,553,920 which is not a multiple of the physical block size 4,096.  To correct the issue, you would need to move or re-create the PV/partition to start on a multiple of 4,096 (e.g. by passing `--dataalignment` to `vgcreate`/`pvcreate` or `--offset` to `cryptsetup`).

Unfortunately, even after the start is corrected, the "alignment inconsistency" message will continue to be printed.  [The conclusion of Sven Eschenberg in a long thread on the dm-crypt list was that some of these checks may yield incorrect warnings.](http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2016-January/004934.html)  In particular, if `sdb` is a USB disk, the optimal I/O size may not be a multiple of the physical sector size (e.g. I have a 4k USB3 disk which reports `physical_block_size` 4,096 and `optimal_io_size` 33,553,920).  These values are correct (as reported by the drive), plausible (due to USB constraints), and are not based on any of the device mapper parameters.

The problem is that the logic in `blk_stack_limits` assumes optimal I/O size will be a multiple of the physical sector size, which is not true for some devices.  Once this is the only issue present, you can safely ignore the warning.

**Update 2019-03-03:**  Unfortunately, several tools may create these incorrectly aligned PVs/partitions.  Relevant issues/fixes:

- [RedHat Bug 1513820](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1513820) for cryptsetup (fixed in v2.0.0 - [b80278c0](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/commit/b80278c0))
- [Debian Bug 923561](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=923561) for parted (not fixed)
- util-linux libfdisk (fixed in v2.27 - [acb7651f8](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/acb7651f8))
- [RedHat Bug 1685787](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1685787) for lvm2 pvcreate (not fixed)

Comment: 33553920 % 4096 = 3584 = 7 sectors. So it isn't a false warning in this case — it's actually misaligned.

Comment: @derobert Although it is true that `optimal_io_size` is not a multiple of `physical_block_size`, neither of these is changeable.  It's not really an alignment issue because it's not affected by the device partitioning/mapping.

Comment: @derobert Ignore my previous reply.  I just realized you were referring to the alignment of the partitions from the log snippet in the original question.  I believe you may be correct that TomHale's partitions are misaligned.

Comment: Is there any way to re-align an existing partition?  I have an encrypted LUKS volume which was working for many months ... until one day it didn't -- I'd really like to be able to retrieve data without reformatting or re-creating the volume.

Comment: Can you read SMART data (via `smartctl`) from the disk?  [If no, this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496606/143394) may help.

Answer (score 1):

[Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_alignment) ensures optimal use of your drive, sometimes software gets this wrong and compensates by using a larger cache, check

```
cat /sys/block/sd?/queue/optimal_io_size
```

to correct that you have to re format (likely both the GPT/LVM layers)
look into --dataalignment and --dataalignmentoffset of pvcreate

Comment: `$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/optimal_io_size` `33553920` 33MB for a 2TB USB HDD? `268431360` for a 4TB???

Comment: @Tom they both should drop to 0 if you fix the alignment

Comment: I'm seeing this, but realised that 33553920 / 512 = 65535. Is it possible something's reporting "-1" as optimal IO size in sectors?

Comment: A weird [`optimal_io_size` is a symptom of this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496606/143394)