# dmsetup luksFormat creating an alignment inconsistency

Tags: linux, encryption, disk, luks, cryptsetup

When unlocking a newly-formatted LUKS volume, I received a warning in the kernel log:

```
kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:14: adding target device sdk1 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=33553920
```

According to another question, a [false warning is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340484/device-mapper-table-alignment-inconsistency), so I confirmed it's a true warning: 33553920 is not divisible by 4096. I further used luksDump to confirm:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdk1  | grep 'Payload offset'
Payload offset: 65535
```

which is not a multiple of 8 (4096 ÷ 512 = 8)

`lsblk -t /dev/sdk` confirms Linux is aware of the alignment requirements:

```
NAME             ALIGNMENT MIN-IO   OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sdk                      0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 cfq       128 128   32M
└─sdk1                   0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 cfq       128 128   32M
```

dmsetup is documented to handle alignment itself, why did it create a misalignment? And are there arguments to luksFormat to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that dmsetup computes its alignment from the optimal I/O size, without bothering to check that that is actually a multiple of the physical block size. As mentioned in the false warning question, this optimal I/O size makes sense due to USB constraints.

So the solution is simple: use `--align-payload` to override the detected value. A value of 8 should work (and produce the smallest possible header); the default when cryptsetup can't tell is documented as 2048. So I went with the default:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdk1 --align-payload 2048 --verify-passphrase --hash sha512 -s 512
```

After that, the payload offset is now 4096 (from luksDump), and a kernel warning is still produced:

```
kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:14: adding target device sdk1 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=2097152
```

... but 2097152 is divisible by 4096, so that's the false warning mentioned in the other question. So the problem is resolved.

Comment: I'm seeing this, but realised that 33553920 / 512 = 65535. Is it possible something's reporting "-1" as optimal IO size in sectors?

Comment: @SteveDee if you chase down the linked question, 65535 sectors is apparently a limit imposed by USB. I haven't researched it myself, so this is speculation, but I wouldn't be surprised if USB/USB storage/etc. (the protocol itself) has an UINT16 somewhere for sector count.