# optimal_io_size is large causing LVM LV alignment inconsistency

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to create a LVM VG and LV, but the LV is not aligned.

Here's my starting position:

```
% lsblk -t /dev/sdd
NAME   ALIGNMENT MIN-IO   OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED       RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sdd            0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
├─sdd1         0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
├─sdd2         0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
└─sdd3         0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
```

Note the `ALIGNMENT`s are all `0` (correct).

On `sdd2`, I create a VG `test` and then a LV `align-me`:

```
% sudo vgcreate --pvmetadatacopies 2 --vgmetadatacopies 2 test /dev/6TBd1p2
  Physical volume "/dev/6TBd1p2" successfully created.
  Volume group "test" successfully created
% sudo lvcreate -L 64g -n align-me test
  Logical volume "align-me" created.
```

However, `ALIGNMENT` for `test-align--me` is wrong:

```
% lsblk -t /dev/sdd
NAME               ALIGNMENT MIN-IO   OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED       RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sdd                        0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
├─sdd1                     0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
├─sdd2                     0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
│ └─test-align--me        -1   4096        0    4096     512    1                 128 128   32M
└─sdd3                     0   4096 33553920    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      60 128   32M
```

I also see the following log message (repeated 4 times):

```
kernel: device-mapper: table: 254:6: adding target device sdd2 caused an alignment inconsistency: physical_block_size=4096, logical_block_size=512, alignment_offset=0, start=33553920
```

I've calling `vgcreate` with `--dataalignmentoffset 4k` and also `--dataalignment` with `1m` and `4m` but the results are the same.

I'm running:

```
LVM version:     2.02.182(2) (2018-10-30)
Library version: 1.02.152 (2018-10-30)
Driver version:  4.39.0
```

Comment: `--dataalignmentoffset 4k` why though? You could try using `--dataalignment` same as PE size (and set PE size to something larger, e.g. `64M`). Mind showing a `vgcfgbackup` (created w/o the offset) and `parted unit s print`?

Comment: also really weird OPT-IO value... stick to MiB alignment no matter what it says

Comment: oh, you already asked the same question here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340484/30851

Comment: Thanks for you pointers @frostschutz. The final answer was a little surprising, but I got there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Symptoms

1. The `lsblk -t` `OPT-IO` value was really high ([pointed out by frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496447/created-lvm-lv-is-not-aligned-but-partition-is-aligned#comment913119_496447))
2. When running `smartctl` on the disk, I was seeing:

   ```
   Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command
   ```

#### Cause

It seems that `-1` is returned if an optimal IO value can't be read.

As [pointed out by Steve Dee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340484/device-mapper-table-alignment-inconsistency#comment779427_369906):

- 33553920 / 512 (logical sector size) = 65535
- -1 represented as a 16 bit value = 65535. (2<sup>16</sup> = 65536)

This `33553920` value is then used by `pvcreate`/`vgcreate` to align the first PE (`pe_start`) as shown by:

```
sudo pvs -o +pe_start --units b
```

#### Work-around

Passing `--dataalignment 1m` to `vgcreate` will have `pe_start` = 1048576B = 1MiB.

This will ensure that `pe_start` is aligned with a disk sector, but the (incorrect) misalignment message will still be printed.

#### Root cause fix

[Disabling UAS](https://askubuntu.com/a/692892/478705) on the drive had the `OPT-IO` value return to `0` (consistent with my other disk drives). It also allowed `smartctl` to be run on the drive.

Passing `--dataalignment 1m` is not needed if this fix is applied.

Comment: Linux has a way of detecting an invalid optimal_io_size and should ignore invalid values by when they are not evenly divisible by the physical block size. Problem is, some usb hdd enclosures don't report the correct physical block size when that check is happening so linux gets it wrong. This should be fixed in a couple of weeks - more on this here: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-scsi/msg139677.html